# Member function in Eigen math library for vector magnitude

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I have been trying to find a method that computes the magnitude of a vector in Eigen and I was not able to. Can somebody provide me with the function name of just if it doesn't exist?

I can create a global method that does the job but I prefer not to.

Comment: A vector in mathematics is different from a CS vector. Exactly what vector are you talking about.

Comment: Martin, CS vectors don't have magnitudes.

Comment: @Martin
I am using http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

and I want to get the magnitude of an Eigen::Vector3f instance I have created.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You want [.norm()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html#title1).  Note that there's also [.squaredNorm()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a229bd5cc6237359a1d85401743476ede), [.normalized()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a8ed1fb2e792b1079639a74e3581fbc74) and [.normalize()](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#acd0de676568888d848beb97dcc53ae47).

Answer (score 5):

The method you're looking for is `.norm()`.